# Custom Items in Angular not making it to Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am sending the following request to my local Web API service.

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common.something = 'anything';
       $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/FantasyTradeAnalyzer/api/home/ListLeagues',

    })
    .success(function (data)
    {
      $http.defaults.headers.common.something = undefined;
    });
```

And the following code in my Web Api Service

```
  [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public LeaguesViewModel ListLeagues(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var re = Request;
    var headers = re.Headers;
    if (headers.Contains("something"))
    { //do stuff }
}
```

However, when I look in Fiddler (and the C# debugger), I do not see the custom field I sent in the Header. What am I missing here? Both things (Angular and Web Api) are hosted in my local IIS, different websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, adding an explicit protocol (`http`) to your URI will cause your header to not get added.  In addition, you should be using the "headers" option in config, which is what gets passed as an object to `$http`.  passing a config option to the config is redundant and will not work, since you are *in* the config object already.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', function($http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'www.google.com/test',
            headers: { 'something': 'anything' } 
        })
        .success(function (data)
        {});

});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gyg2am8z/)

Alternatively, you could use the shorthand `.get()` method on `$http`.

```
$http.get(www.google.com/test', { 
    'something': 'anything' } 
)
```

It's worth noting a few caveats:

If you are performing any sort of update or change based on your custom header, you should send either a POST or PATCH since there is a side affect and you are not simply *just* retrieving data That said, there are times where a GET needs to and should be sent with custom headers.

This replaces all headers, so you would need to re-add in any applicable headers that you need, since it functions as an override according to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

> In addition, you can supply a headers property in the config object
>   passed when calling $http(config), which overrides the defaults
>   without changing them globally.

Finally, if you want to avoid removing default headers, another option is to globally modify the defaults for that header, although you would then want to remove it after the request.  This is clunky and awkward, but it eliminates the need for you to manually rebuild your headers.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', function($http) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.something = 'anything';

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'www.google.com/test' 
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common.something = undefined;
        });
});
```

To retrieve the header in your WebAPI method:

```
var foo = request.Headers.GetValues("test").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No it is still a get. All I did was modify the signature to this. 
public LeaguesViewModel ListLeagues(HttpRequestMessage request)
If I take out everything header related, it hits the service just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91944/discussion-between-isaac-levin-and-david-l).

Comment: is this supposed to be this difficult? Is there some nuget package or tutorial that show this exact case?

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1185/aspnet-web-api-versioning-angularjs-app seems to be pretty darn close to what you are trying to do.  Might be a worthwhile read.

Comment: Thanks for the Link @DavidL. I got it working based on the example. The odd thing is that with this method, the service is called twice, one without the custom headers as an OPTIONS, and the 2nd with the header as a GET. Is this by design?

Comment: No, that sounds like a bug in your code.  None of my fiddle testing ever sent two requests.

Comment: Well I downloaded the example, built and ran and it makes 2 calls.

Comment: after reading more into this. The first OPTIONS request is by design. You have to modify Web Api intercept this OPTIONS request so your action is not invoked. You can do this by installing CORs nuget package and EnablingCors in the the WebApiConfig

Comment: @IsaacLevin Ah, that makes perfect sense.  As an aside, you can also use a proxy like xdomain for cross-domain calls. That's often required when your API does not live in the same project as your javascript.